# Prove two polynomials are equal in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

The task is to prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{Q_1(x)-Q_2(x)}{\|x\|^k}=0 \implies Q_1=Q_2,$$ where $Q_1,Q_2$ are polynomials of degree $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It's known that:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a x^\alpha}{\|x\|^n}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
0 \textrm{ if } |\alpha|>n \\
a \textrm { if }  |\alpha|=n \\
\infty \textrm { if }  |\alpha|<n \textrm{ and } a\neq 0 \\
0 \textrm{ if } a=0
\end{array}\right.
$$ and $$|\alpha|=k=\alpha_1!\alpha_2!\cdot...\cdot\alpha_n!$$

Proof by contradiction. Assume that $Q_{1}\neq{Q_2}$ and let's denote $Q_1(x)-Q_2(x)=F(x)+G(x)$ where $F$ is lowest degree ($l$) polynomial and and $G$ contains the rest. Then let's consider the limit  $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(tb)+G(tb)}{\|tb\|^l},$$ where $b\neq{0}$ and $F(b)\neq{0}$.

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(tb)+G(tb)}{\|tb\|^l}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{G(tb)}{\|tb\|^l}+\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(tb)}{\|tb\|^l}=...\neq{0}$$ which is contradiction. Therefore it must hold that $Q_1=Q_2$.

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(tb)+G(tb)}{\|tb\|^l}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t^lF(b)+t{^\alpha}G(b)}{|t|^l\|b\|^l}$$, where $|\alpha|>l$

I have problem expanding the limit expression.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $F(x)$ polynomial of $l$ degree, then what you can do with $F(tb)$ (and similarly with $G(tb)$) if $t$ is real number? (For example consider $f(x)=x^2$) and how you can write $f(tx)$).

Comment: How would you apply same to $F(tx)$ if its degree is $l$?

Comment: $$F(tb)=t^lF(b)$$ $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(tb)+G(tb)}{\|tb\|^l}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t^lF(b)+t{^\alpha}G(b)}{|t|^l\|b\|^l}$$, where $|\alpha|>l$

Comment: You can just cancel terms $t^l$ and take limit and see that it doesn't equal to zero.

Comment: $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(tb)+G(tb)}{\|tb\|^l}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t^lF(b)+t{^\alpha}G(b)}{|t|^l\|b\|^l}$. Here absolute value has a sign plus or minus depending on what value it is, but you could write $|t^l|$ as $\pm t^l$, but it does not matter what sign is, since limit will still not be zero.

Comment: $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{F(tb)+G(tb)}{\|tb\|^l}=a\pm\frac{F(b)}{\|b\|^l}?$$